# How to enforce that group X membership implies group Y membership in Puppet?

Tags: arch-linux, puppet

I'd like all users who are members of the 'users' group to also be members of the 'audio', 'lp' and 'video' groups. How can I enforce this in Puppet **without specifying any of the usernames?** The goal would be something like the following:

```
user { something_that_resolves_to_all_usernames_in_the_users_group
  groups => ['audio', 'lp', 'video'],
  auth_membership => false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom fact to build a user/group list from /etc/group and then use `filter.keys` or `reduce` to create an array of chosen users, depending on the need.

Once you have that array, you can apply anything you want to those users.